# Which lifecyce callback suits better connectin to servers/brokers

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onresume

In the App i am developing, I have to connect to a server/broker to send and receive some messages to and from the `broker`, and also I have to provide a callback synchronous and an asynchronous listener. As far as I understand, such operation should be better placed in `onResume()`. am I right? please guide me and confirm whether `onResume` is the best place to connect to servers/brokers with callbacks or they woud better be inside other lifecycle callback?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably will do something with your UI as soon as you have the answer from the server, you'll want to contact it only when your UI has been created and set up. 
`OnCreate` is fine in an `Activity` (after `setContentView` and assigning your Views), `OnViewCreated` for a `Fragment`. As long as you're 'prepared' to receive the server's answer instantaniously, it doesn't really matter.

Remember that most 'startup' lifecycle callbacks will be called again if the screen rotates, so don't do the server call twice if you don't have to.